# How to change the content of an imported component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I created a `header` component. Here is the html (`header.component.html`):

```
<section class="container global-header-presentation">
  <div class="header-presentation" *ngFor="let elem of myFormTemplate">
     <h1 class="title">{{elem.title}}</h1>    
  </div>
</section>
```

here is the code (`header.component.ts'):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormTemplateDataService } from '../services/form-template-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  myFormTemplate: any = []

  constructor(
    private formTemplateDataService: FormTemplateDataService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formTemplateDataService.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
      this.myFormTemplate = data;
    })
  }
}
```

This component receives data from a local json file from a service.
Here my service (`form-template-data-service.service.ts`):

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class FormTemplateDataService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }

    public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get("./assets/templates/headers/projects.json");
    }
}
```

And here my local json (`projects.json`):

```
[
    {
        "title":"Projects",
        "subtitle":"Click on a box to add or update items in your plan",
        "type": "linkBox"
    },
    {
        "title":"Other Projects",
        "subtitle":"Click on a box to add or update items in your plan",
        "type": "linkBox"
    }
]
```

**What I would like to do:**
Implement my component `<app-header></app-header>` in all the other components of my application, but be able to change its content (the title, the subtitles, the text etc) according to the component in which I implemented it.
For example, if I implement my header component (`<app-header></app-header>`) in the `'Projects'` component, the title will be **'Projects'** but if I implement my header component (`<app-header></app-header>`) in the `'Other Projects'` component, the title will be **'Other Projects'**. 
And I would like all the data to be saved in the local json I have.
Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You could achieve the first requirement with Angular [`input`](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) property, but I don't think you can directly write to the JSON file from the front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Input() decorater should work wonders here.

Header ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormTemplateDataService } from '../services/form-template-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  myFormTemplate: any = []
  Input() pageTitle: string;
  constructor(
    private formTemplateDataService: FormTemplateDataService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formTemplateDataService.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
      this.myFormTemplate = data;
    })
  }
}
```

Parent component

```html
<app-header pageTitle="sampleTitle"></app-header>
```

Header html

```html
     <h1 class="title">{{pageTitle}}</h1>
```

In this example the title is just a hardcoded string but this can be dynamicly set from the parent component of the header component.